I want to show the keyboard and menu toggles in mathlive only if the element is focussed
We can hide the keyboard-toggle using
math-field::part(virtual-keyboard-toggle) {
    display: none;
}

As the default display is flex, I'd hoped to be able to show the toggle when the field is focussed using
math-field:focus math-field::part(virtual-keyboard-toggle) {
    display: flex;
}

But, this has no effect.   The math-field:focus seems to work as I can use it to change (for example) the background.   Is this possible?

I don't understand the syntax. Are you sure it shouldn't be math-field:focus::part(virtual-keyboard-toggle)?

Sorry for the late response.   Somehow missed it.   Thanks.  That works.   If you turn it into an answer I'll mark it.
